# It is possible to implement Adapter Authentication on Mobile First Starter over Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to implement Adapter Authentication on Mobile First Starter container on IBM Bluemix.

*The kernel of the question is:*

Is there a security test already configured in the authenticationConfig.xml that can be use for that? If not, its possible to create it?

As I know, I will need:

1) A security test like:

```
<customSecurityTest name="AuthSecurityTest">
  <test realm="AuthRealm" isInternalUserID="true" /
</customSecurityTest>
```

2) A Realm like:

```
<realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="AuthRealm">
  <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
  <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
  <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
</realm>
```

3) A Login Module like:

```
<loginModule name="AuthLoginModule">
  <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

I'm looking forward for a positive answer.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this built-in.
You need to implement it in you MobileFirst project and then you need to add it to your image and upload your image to your container.

If you're using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, follow this (assuming you are a paying IBM customer with entitlement to download the required artifacts): https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

Comment: Adar, just to share information about this topic here, I'm studying the Mobile Client Access to handle the authentication. This is not a direct answer for my question as you did, but is an alternative and cheaper way to meet the requirements of authentication of the App.